# Trouble iterating with two columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working on a project analyzing student loans. I am comparing student loans based on gender, but I seem to have run into a problem. When I add the sum of the loan column in of the dataset, I get a different number than the sum of both genders combined. Here is my code.

```
print(male, female)
```

> 286 70

```
f_sum = 0

m_sum = 0

for i in df['LoanAmount']:
  for x in df['Gender']:
    if x == 'Female':
        f_sum += i
    else:
        m_sum += i

print('Total Sum of LoanAmount:', df['LoanAmount'].sum())

print('Sum of Both Genders:', f_sum + m_sum)
```

> Total Sum of LoanAmount: 49280.0
>
> Sum of Both Genders: 128872

Am I doing something wrong here? I realize that this may not be enough information, and if you have any questions I am happy to answer.

Comment: Also the first statement about print(male, female) is how many males and females there are in the dataset. Forgot to mention that

Comment: Why are you using a for-loop? You should be using vectorized sum... this is why you use a data-frame at all...

Comment: yes, you really want something like `df.groupby('Gender').LoanAmount.sum()`  ...

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to group by gender and then sum the loan amounts:

```
df.groupy('Gender').sum()['LoanAmount']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the dataframe twice it seems, once for each loanAmount and then for each gender. What you want to do is apply a filter to your dataframe instead.
You can do this as follows:

```
female_sum = df[df['Gender']=='Female']['LoanAmount'].sum()
male_sum = df[df['Gender']=='Male']['LoanAmount'].sum()
```

Comment: How could I do that, sorry I am a little new to python.

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

To sum the loan amount for each gender, you should use:

```
male_loans = df.loc[df.Gender == 'Male', 'LoanAmount'].sum()
female_loans = df.loc[df.Gender == 'Female', 'LoanAmount'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the data by gender and sum them up:

```
    f_sum = df[df['Gender'] == 'Female']['LoanAmount'].sum()
    m_sum = df[df['Gender'] == 'Male']['LoanAmount'].sum()
```